# Angular issue with SSL certificates

Tags: angular, http, proxy, http-proxy

Good day
I have a localhost which works with HTTPS requests with self sifned SSL certificates in root of project. Here is `PROXY_CONF file`:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [{
    context: [
        "/production/items"
    ],
    target: "http://resourse.1.com",
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
}];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Here is `environment.prod.ts` file:

```
 export const environment = {
  production: true,
  api: 'https://resourse.1.com/production/item-backend/v1',
  auth: 'https://resourse.1.com/production/item-backend/v1',
};
```

After deply to real working domainI have the following erros in console: `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

What am I doing wrong ? Why in built project HTTPS returns a error inspite of created certs in project ?!

here is the part of angular.json

```
 "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "amlapp:build",
            "ssl": true,
            "sslKey": "./ssl/localhost.key",
            "sslCert": "./ssl/localhost.crt",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "amlapp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
```

Comment: First what I can see is `/production/items` doesn't exist in your paths `api` and `auth`. I think first you have to change this: `/production/items` to: `/production/item-backend/`. After that try following in env file: `export const environment = {
  production: true, baseUrl: 'https://resourse.1.com', api: '/production/item-backend/v1', auth: '/production/item-backend/v1' };` then gather them together when you make a http call as URL in your services. It depends on your concept.

Comment: Also in proxy file you have no `https` and `secure` is set to `false`, but the URLs in `api` and `auth` you are using: `https`, not `http`